# How to count the total number of residues in a sequence with awk?

Tags: awk

I have a text file that contains protein sequences. I would like to get the total number of residues in each sequence. How can I do this with awk?

```
>1GS9
PYCPAAVIAPVV
>1LE2
DFEFAKWKN
>1NFN
ADAPPDS
```

Desired output

```
1GS9 - 12
1LE2 - 9
1NFN - 7
```

Comment: `>1GS9
PYCPAAVIAPVV` means you call `1GS9` and it returns `PYCPAAVIAPVV` ??

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234739/how-to-calculate-the-total-number-of-specific-residues-in-protein-sequences-usin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read every odd line automatically with `{ ... }` and proteins in even lines with `getline`:

```
awk ' {
    getline prot;
    printf "%s - %d\n", substr( $0, 2 ), length( prot ) 
}' infile
```

Output:

```
1GS9 - 12
1LE2 - 9
1NFN - 7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^>/ {
   name=substr($0,2);
   getline;
   printf("%s - %d\n", name, length($1))
}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
 awk '/^>/ { res=substr($0, 2); } /^[^>]/ { print res " - " length($0); }' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{line=substr($0,2);getline;print line,"-",length($0)}' temp
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
>1GS9
PYCPAAVIAPVV
>1LE2
DFEFAKWKN
>1NFN
ADAPPDS
> awk '{line=substr($0,2);getline;print line,"-",length($0)}' temp
1GS9 - 12
1LE2 - 9
1NFN - 7
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU awk):

```
awk -vRS='>' -vOFS=' - ' 'NR>1{print $1,length($2)}' file
```