# How to calculate the total number of specific residues in protein sequences using awk?

Tags: awk

I have some protein sequences. I would like to calculate the the total number of A and L residues in each sequence.

```
>p1
ALASDEKI
>p2
KLHMNA
>p3
GQMLAALM
```

Desired output

```
ptn   A+L

p1     3
p2     2
p3     4
```

How can I do this with awk?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950059/how-to-count-the-total-number-of-residues-in-a-sequence-with-awk)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Records in your file span to multiple lines. So you can use awk `-v RS=''` option.

### command

```
sed 's/>/\n/' input |
    awk -vRS='' -vOFS='\t' '
        BEGIN{
            print "ptn","A+L"
        }
        {
            gsub(/[^AL]/,"",$2)
            print $1,length($2)
        }'
```

### output

```
ptn A+L
p1  3
p2  2
p3  4
```